# ¿Por qué se genera este bucle infinito?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
boolean repetir1;
do {
  repetir1 = false;
  try {
    System.out.println("\nElije el equipo del cual quieras ver la información introducienco su número(1-8) o introduce un 9 para verlos todos a la vez. Introduce un 0 para cerrar este menú.");
    intRes1 = kb.nextInt();
    if (intRes1 < 0 || intRes1 > 9) {
      throw new MyException(1);
    }
  } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Porfavor introduce un número entero.");
    repetir1 = true;
  } catch (MyException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    repetir1 = true;
  }
} while (repetir1 == true);
```

Cuando se lanza la excepción `MyException` el bucle funciona bien, pero cuando se lanza la excepción `InputMismatchException` por alguna razón que desconozco el bucle empieza a repetirse infinitamente omitiendo la entrada por teclado. Es probable que el problema venga por algo que desconozco sobre las excepciones puesto que estoy empezando a usarlas ahora.

Comment: debes limpiar el scanner luego de causar el Imputmismatch podes hacerlo poniendo kb.nextLine();  dentro del primer catch

Comment: Era eso, muchas gracias de verdad.